# signal handler does not work after threads are launched

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, sigint

I think similar questions were already asked in SOF. However, I could not really find a proper solution for my particular case. I am trying to make a daemon that will open up few worker threads on launch and keep on running till SIGTERM is received. Upon receiving SIGTERM, the parent thread will terminate all the worker threads and the entire process will stop. This is how my code looks like:

```
from lib.threadrunner import ThreadRunner
import signal
import time

def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Stop pressing the CTRL+C!'

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)

objectToRun = ClassToRun(cfg)

time.sleep(3)

# The below code uses threading module to create 3 threads
threadRunner = ThreadRunner()
threadRunner.load('Task Name', objectToRun)
threadRunner.start(3)
threadRunner.joinAll()
```

If I hit `Ctrl + C` to send a SIGINT after all the threads are started, the `sigint_handler` function does not triggered, cause nothing gets printed out. However, if I can hit `Ctrl + C` before the threads are launched (during the 3 sec sleep time added) I do see `Stop pressing the CTRL+C!` printed. Im not sure why this is acting like this and how I may solve this.

PS: if you need the code of the `threadRunner` class I will provide that aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by adding an infinite loop in the parent thread. So the updated code looks like this:

```
from lib.threadrunner import ThreadRunner
import signal
import time

RUN = True

def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Stop pressing the CTRL+C!'
    global RUN
    RUN = False

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)

objectToRun = ClassToRun(cfg)

time.sleep(3)

# The below code uses threading module to create 3 threads
threadRunner = ThreadRunner()
threadRunner.load('Task Name', objectToRun)
threadRunner.start(3)
# threadRunner.joinAll()

while RUN:
    time.sleep(1)
```

My observation says, as there was no more codes to execute after launching the threads, the parent thread goes to an inactive state. Thats why the `SIGINT` did not get handled properly. However, the loop keeps the parent thread alive and hence `SIGINT` were handled properly. However, this is just based on my observation. If somebody can comeup with a proper explanation that would be great.